# How to qcut unevenly distributed data?

Tags: pandas

Consider the following example

```py
pd.qcut([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3], q=2, duplicates="drop")
```

Given that the number of 1s has exceeded 50% (1/q), I would expect two bins that group 1, and (2, 3) to be formed.

To my surprise, Only one bin is generated (0.999, 3.0]. How do I qcut data with high concentration on some values?